# If $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix that satisfies $A^2=A$, then prove that $\operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{rank}(I-A)=n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix that satisfies $A^2=A$, then prove that $\operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{rank}(I-A)=n$.

I already proved that $\operatorname{Im}(A)=\operatorname{Ker}(I-A)$, but I can't go further.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For any matrix $M$: $\operatorname{rank}(M) = \dim( \operatorname{Im}(M))$. Now how are $\dim( \operatorname{Im}(M))$ and $\dim( \operatorname{Ker}(M))$ related?

Comment: You haven't proved that Im(A)=Ker(I-A). You asked the others to do so in  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4317269

Comment: Hint: show the image of $(I-A)$ is equal to the null space of $A$. Then the result follows from the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: HINT:  dim(Im($A$)) + dim(Im($I-A$))= dim(Ker($I-A$)) + dim(Im($I-A$)) = $n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $A^{2} = A \Rightarrow A - A^{2} = (I - A)A = 0$. For $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, we have $(I - A)Av = (I - A)(Av) = 0 \Rightarrow Av \in \text{ker}(I - A) \Rightarrow \text{im}(A) \subseteq \text{ker}(I - A)$. Next, suppose $v \in \text{ker}(I - A)$. Then $(I - A)v = 0 \Rightarrow v = Av \in \text{im}(A) \Rightarrow \text{ker}(I - A) \subseteq \text{im}(A)$. Thus, $\text{im}(A) = \text{ker}(I - A)$.

By the rank-nullity theorem,

$$n = \text{dim}(\text{ker}(I - A)) + \text{rank}(I - A) = \text{rank}(A) + \text{rank}(I - A)$$